# PHP regex to convert dimensions like N*N and NxN into N x N

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

I have a series of search terms entered by users, asking the same thing in different ways. For example someone is searching for frame `8 x 10 frame`. They often search in the following ways:

```
8x10 frame
8*10 frame
8 * 10 frame
8 x 10 frame
8x10 photo frame
```

Stylistically, I prefer `N x N`, so I would prefer to convert all variations of `NxN`, `N*N`, `N * N` into `N x N`.

Examples:

`8x10 frame` -> `8 x 10 frame`
`8*10 frame` -> `8 x 10 frame`
`8x10 photo frame` -> `8 x 10 photo frame`

I've tried using str_replace, but there are so many if-else conditions my code has become unmanageable. I feel like I'm not the first to have this issue, hoping some nice regex or build-in function exists.

EDIT: I used "8 x 10" as an example, but we need to consider any custom combinations like "4 x 3", "12 x 4" and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a regular expression, you can use...

```
echo preg_replace("/(\d+)\s*[Xx\*]\s*(\d+)/", "$1 x $2", $a);
```

the pattern is

```
(\d+) - Any number of digits
\s* - 0 or more spaces
[Xx\*] - either X, x or *
\s* - 0 or more spaces
(\d+) - Any number of digits
```

which gets replaced with `"$1 x $2"`, so this gives the consistent output.

Answer (score 1):

Match a digit, then zero or one space, then either an `x` or a `*`, then zero or one space, then a digit.

If you'd rather have "zero or more" instead of "zero or one", then replace the `?`s with `*`s.

The `\K` restarts the fullstring match -- so it "forgets" the first matched digit.

The "lookahead" ensures that the digit after the dimension-delimiter is found but not included in the fullstring match.

Using the `i` pattern modifier means case-insensitive matching.

With this pattern you don't need to bother capturing whole number sequences and your replacement string is much simpler to read.

A `*` inside of a character class never needs to be escaped.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/VG7b6))

```
$strings = [
    '8x10 frame',
    '8*10 frame',
    '8 * 10 frame',
    '8 x 10 frame',
    '8x10 photo frame'
];

var_export(preg_replace('~\d\K ?[x*] ?(?=\d)~i', ' x ', $strings));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '8 x 10 frame',
  1 => '8 x 10 frame',
  2 => '8 x 10 frame',
  3 => '8 x 10 frame',
  4 => '8 x 10 photo frame',
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `str_replace` seems to work pretty well. If you have a large number of conversions that need to be done it would be pretty easy to write a couple of more lines of code to build the look for and change to arrays.

```
$data    = ['8x10 frame','8*10 frame','8 * 10 frame','8 x 10 frame','8x10 photo frame'];
$look4   = ['*','8*' ,'8x' ,'x10','  '];
$change2 = ['x','8 *','8 x','x 10',' '];

foreach ($data as $entry) {
    echo '*' . $entry . '* -> *' . str_replace($look4,$change2,$entry) . '*' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, I like this. I do need to tweak my question. I used `8 x 10` as an example, but the dimensions could be anything like `4 x 3`, `12*6` and so on - lots of combinations! :)

Comment: Which is why I said that a little bit of code to build the arrays being used might be needed. If you want to cover probably everything just build it once from 1 to 1000 or whatever maximum suits your need.